# Cannot deploy JBoss 7.1.1 Final, Java EE 6 and Intellij IDEA 14.1.4

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, jboss, ejb

Im triying to deploy a little application but when I press run with de JBoss configuration, I get this Exception:

```
    13:46:04,768 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."agenda5_war_exploded.war#manager1": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."agenda5_war_exploded.war#manager1": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: manager1] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @462d62d9 (roots: /Users/coolmyplanet/Downloads/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:101)
    ... 23 more

JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."agenda5_war_exploded.war#manager1": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."agenda5_war_exploded.war#manager1": Failed to start service
```

My persistence.xml, I search in other posts but I can't fix the problem. Im new in JBoss and Intellij IDEA.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="2.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>modelo.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_app"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**NEW**

I fix the error by putting the JTA datasource in persistence.xml, but JBoss is telling me that this data source is missing.

```
service jboss.naming.context.java.sample (missing)
```

Comment: Have you included mysql Driver in modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main with module.xml

Comment: Yes I included it. The error it was that I don't specify the datasource in persistence.xml. I have this line:

`<jta-data-source>agenda_app@localhost</jta-data-source>`

But is missing, what is the correct name?

Comment: it should be like <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/***</jta-data-source>

Comment: I try your solution but isn't work. I assign the data source sample to my persistence unit manager1 and put this new line in persistence.xml:

`<jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>`

Comment: Error is like ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  mainly it couldn't load driver check module.xml

Comment: The complete error is:

`service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.sample (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."agenda5_war_exploded.war#manager1"]`

Comment: what version of jboss are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a module dependency on the MySQL module you added.

The documentation is here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

You can use Maven WAR plugin to add the Dependencies: com.mysql line in the MANIFEST.MF file. Or you can add a jboss-deployment.xml file.

Comment: Yes is the correct way to install the MySQL driver. Thanks for the answer.